# Relationship with referenced document in Couchbase

Tags: java, relationship, spring-data-couchbase

I am using Couchbase 4.0.0 with Spring Data Couchbase 1.3.2, and want to persist the relationships using referenced document instead of embedded.
For example, the document is as the following:

```
{
   title: "Some Title",
   pages: 123,
   publisher: {
              name: "O'Reilly Media",
              location: "CA"
            }
}
```

But I want the documents like this:

```
{
   _id: "oreilly",
   name: "O'Reilly Media",
   location: "CA"
}

{
   _id: 123456789,
   title: "Some Title",
   pages: 123,
   publisher_id: "oreilly"
}
```

I have 2 different classes to represent the data and I'm using the annotations `@Document` and `@Field`. I already tried the annotation `@ManyToOne` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is currently no support of `@ManyToOne` type document relations in Spring Data Couchbase. Quite importantly this annotation is provided by `JPA` and not part of Spring Data itself (not a common thing across all the stores backing Spring Data).

Note that `1.3.2` is quite an old version, and the Spring Data Couchbase connector has since then been almost entirely rewritten in `2.0.0` (and `2.1.0` is just around the corner).

There was some significant upgrades to Spring Data Couchbase features in this 2.0.0 version, and that idea of storing sub-objects as separated documents was thrown around, as an idea. It could make it in a future version, but there's no definite roadmap for it.
Edit: if that feature gets added, it won't be before at least version 2.2.0

Comment: Hi Simon,
Thanks for your help. 
Considering my documents are already stored in couchbase, do you know some way to tell Spring that the sub-objects are in separated documents in a read operation?

Comment: unfortunately, no I don't

Comment: Ok, but I still have a doubt. What happens if I have a circular reference? Spring will embed sub objects recursively?

Comment: Is there any play at the moment to add this feature? I was also looking for such kind of feature.

Comment: I am using spring-data-couchbase 3.1.3, is this features added on this version??